# X axis shows the time from 12 till 12:55 instead of dates

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

This code generates a highchart with 2 Y axis and 1 X:

```
$('#main_chart').highcharts({
      chart: {
          zoomType: 'xy'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Overview'
      },
      xAxis: [{
          type: 'datetime'
      }],
      yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
          labels: {
              format: '${value}',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
              }
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Y1',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
              }
          }
      }, { // Secondary yAxis
          title: {
              text: 'Y2',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
          },
          labels: {
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
          },
          opposite: true
      }],
      tooltip: {
          shared: true
      },
      legend: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'left',
          x: 120,
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          y: 100,
          floating: true,
          backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
      },
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
      },
      series: [{
          name: 'Y1',
          data: y1Data
      }
      ,{
          name: 'Y2',
          data: y2Data
      }
      ]        
  });
```

y1Data and y2Data are the arrays of arrays `[[1426525200, 2], [1426611600, 0], [1426698000, 0]...]` where the 1st element is date. The dates are sequent with a step of 1 day:

`1 Mar 2015, 2 Mar 2015, 3 Mar 2015....`

However, I see only time from 12:00 till 12:55 on X and nothing else:

[image]

What I want to see is the dates `1 Mar 2015, 2 Mar 2015, 3 Mar 2015.... EndDate`. Moreover, why is there minus $20? There're no negative values in the data set.

Comment: Since this issue is about defining date type data for Highcharts lib, consider renaming the question to something more general, maybe 'X-axis shows incorrect time based on (my) timestamp'? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining data, either provide timestamp in **miliseconds** (not seconds) or use JavaScript Date object instead:

```
var y1Data = [[new Date(), 2], [1426611600000, 0], [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 0]];
```

To answer your `$-20` question, Highcharts use their own algorithm to *guess* the most appropriate axis minimums a maximus. If you're not happy with it, simply set

```
yAxis: {
   min: 0,
   ...
}
```

Comment: I already have all data in y1Data and y2Date in the correct format prepared on the server, why would I change it on the client again?

Comment: Data already prepared on the server? Ok, just add three zeros (000) so that they are in miliseconds.

Comment: now I see 1970-2015 years. The dates are already in UTC format, do I really need to modify them on the client?

Comment: If you see 1970-2015 years, there's probably one (or more) record that is broken. Double check the dates that arrive from the server.